# Import all emails into SP

Tags: exchange-server

I'd like to know if it's possible to have SP connect to Exchange on a timed interval and pull in all new emails for the logged in user. The user will then classify the emails into the correct "list".

Answer (score 0):

[Enable and configure e-mail support for a list or library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/enable-and-configure-e-mail-support-for-a-list-or-library-HA010082307.aspx),
or write a webpart to display email , and a timer job to sync with exchange.